# Detect click on a 2D game object without Update function

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple click game in Unity. I have a canvas under which I have placed a game object with a raw image of a house. I put a Circle Collider 2D on the game object as well as a script. Now I want to detect if user clicks on the collider and if so open a popup. Due to performance I would like to keep it outside of update loop.

I would like something like this in the script but it didn't debug.log anything:

```
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log("clicked");
}
```

I tried IPointerClickHandler with the function OnPointerClick which worked, but it detected clicks on the entire game object and not just on the collider.

How can I detect clicks on just the collider?

Comment: do you hav an event system in your scene?

Comment: @BugFinder, yes

Answer (score 0):

Make shure the z index of your clickable object is big enough to not be blocked by other objects

Comment: It is, and it was working with IPointerClickHandler

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[Collider2D].OverlapPoint` function to determine if a point is contained within a collider.  It requires a world space point, which can be obtained by converting your mouse position using your camera or through the pointer event data from the current raycast (when using the IPointer callbacks).

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Click2D : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Collider2D clickableCollider;

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (clickableCollider.OverlapPoint(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition))
        {
            Debug.Log($"Clicked {clickableCollider.name}");
        }
    }
}
```